# How to return dominant topic, percent contribution and topic keywords to original model

Tags: python, gensim, lda, mallet

There are a lot of examples of LDA Mallet topic modelling however non of them shows how to add dominant topic, percent contribution and topic keywords to the original dataframe. 
Let's assume this is the dataset and my code

## Dataset:

```
Document_Id   Text
1             'Here goes one example sentence that is generic'
2             'My car drives really fast and I have no brakes'
3             'Your car is slow and needs no brakes'
4             'Your and my vehicle are both not as fast as the airplane'
```

## Code

```
# Gensim
import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data_above.csv')
data = df.Text.values.tolist() 
# Assuming I have done all the preprocessing, lemmatization and so on and ended up with data_lemmatized:

# Create Dictionary
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_lemmatized)

# Create Corpus
texts = data_lemmatized

# Term Document Frequency
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, 
        id2word=id2word, 
        num_topics=50,random_state=100, 
        chunksize = 1000, update_every=1, 
        passes=10, alpha='auto', per_word_topics=True)
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work...

```
def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel, corpus, df):
    # Init output
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Get main topic in each document
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # => dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
    sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']
    # Add original text to the end of the output
    contents = df
    sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
    return(sent_topics_df)
```

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

I used this code in my project, too. It gives you the topic keywords and the dominant topic in each document.

To get the document percent contribution in each topic, you can use this:

```
topics_docs = list()
for m in ldamallet[corpus]:
    topics_docs.append(m)

topics_docs_dict = dict()
for i in range(len(df)):
    topics_docs_dict[df.loc[i]["Document_Id"]] = [doc for (topic, doc) in topics_docs[i]]

topics_docs_df = pd.DataFrame(data=topics_docs_dict)
docs_topics_df = topics_docs_df.transpose()
```

by the code above, you will have documents in docs_topics_df's rows, topics in docs_topics_df's columns, and percent contribution in each cell.

** My code works but it might not be the most efficient solution. Please edit my code if you can make it better or provide another solution.

Comment: Does something like this exist for the normal (non mallet) gensim LDA model?